# HTML filtering settings in Plone 4?

Tags: plone, genericsetup

Is there a way to configure the HTML filtering settings in Plone 4 through GenericSetup?
Otherwise is there some example code for modifying the HTML filtering settings through Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://collective-docs.plone.org/misc/portal_transforms.html

Comment: Also related is: How to add a new portal_transforms mimetype https://web.archive.org/web/20120406045506/http://plone.org/documentation/kb/portal-transforms/tutorial-all-pages

Answer (score 2):

The portal_transforms example you found is certainly the correct way to make changes to settings that can't be done directly through GenericSetup, but if you want to find out if there's a an xml configuration that will do the job, it's often convenient to use the ZMI to dump all the GS settings.  Go to your site's `/portal_setup/manage_exportSteps`, select `Export all steps` and then examine the resulting xml files in the download, to find one that contains the settings you're looking for.  Not pretty, but surprisingly functional!